# Visual Studio 2008 debug does not stop on error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a simple Windows App written in Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.0, C#).

Without making any change to the project, solution or Visual Studion (from what I can remember), something weird is happening: when I debug (or run) my application, when it hits an error, Visual Studio does not show me any messagebox with the error, and does not stop execution. It "looks" like nothing happened... the code after the error is not executed, but everything else continues to behave like nothing had happened.

What might be wrong?

Comment: 1. Does your application contain debuggable data, whatever mode you are running it in (DEBUG or RELEASE)? If not, then probably there is a crash involved. 2. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click Debug, Exceptions (Ctrl+D, E) and tell Visual Studio to break on all exceptions.

Note that this will break on all *thrown* exceptions, not just all unhandled exceptions; that may not be what you want.

Comment: In Debug - Exceptions I checked all the options in column "Thrown". They were all unchecked, and only User-unhandled column was checked. It works as a charm now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a try catch block? See if your catch block has code to handle the exception (either a messagebox showing what the exception is or logging that exception).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

From tools menu goto `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` -> `Build and Run`
from `On run when build or deployment errors occur`, the combobox selects `Prompt` to launch.